# Android runOnUiThread calling onResume() again

Tags: android, runnable

In my onResume() I have something like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {     
    super.onResume();
            abc();
    }
```

and in abc() I have:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {             
   public void run() {
      MainActivity.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
     //some code
     }
  });
    }
 }).start();
 //do something
```

However it seems runOnUiThread calls onResume through the runOnUiThread because I notice //do something is done twice...

I wonder if there is a work around? Basically I need abc() to wait 10 seconds and then display a message in a textfield on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I need abc() to wait 10 seconds and then display a message in a textfield on the screen.
```

You can use a `Handler`. In `abc()`

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
             public void run() { 
                // do something
             } 
        }, 10000);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

```
public final boolean postDelayed (Runnable r, long delayMillis)

Added in API level 1
Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.

Parameters
r   The Runnable that will be executed.
delayMillis The delay (in milliseconds) until the Runnable will be executed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add code below code in abc().

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //do your task
     }
});
```

Comment: sleep on a ui thread. you are blocking the ui thread. wrong. You should never block the ui thread. Its mentioned in the docs if you want to check